# PHP check user subscription

Tags: php

php below and I want to check if user subscription date has already passed. Below code doesn't work. And my user table looks like (id, unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, is_active, created_at, exp_date)

```
<?php

require("config.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {

  $response = array("error" => FALSE);

  $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email";

  $query_params = array(
    ':email' => $_POST['email']
  );

  try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
  } catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
    die(json_encode($response));
  }

  $validated_info = false;
  $login_ok = false;
  $email = $_POST['email'];

  $row = $stmt->fetch();

  if (password_verify($_POST['password'],$row['encrypted_password'])) {
    $login_ok = true;
  }

  if ($row['created_at'] <= $row['exp_date']) {
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["message"] = "Subscription ended!";
    die(json_encode($response));
  }

  if ($login_ok == true) {
    $response["error"] = false;
    $response["message"] = "Login successful!";
    $response["user"]["uid"] = $row["unique_id"];
    $response["user"]["name"] = $row["name"];
    $response["user"]["email"] = $row["email"];
    $response["user"]["is_active"] = $row["is_active"];
    $response["user"]["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
    $response["user"]["exp_date"] = $row["exp_date"];
    die(json_encode($response));
  } else {
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["message"] = "잘못된 로그인 정보!";
    die(json_encode($response));
  } 

} else {
  echo 'Nothing here';
}

?>
```

Please, any help is appreciated. Sorry my bad English.

Comment: Should your comparison of `$row['exp_date']` be against todays date rather than `$row['created_at']`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You say your code does not work, can you add exacty what does not work, do you get an error message, what are the values for the dates you are comparing etc?  This will help people to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use date_format(php function) to compare dates and compare Subscription expiry date with today's date. Im not sure why you are comparing with created_at.

$date_today = date("m/d/Y"); //use your own date format you are getting from DB, also use the time stamp Y-m-d H:i:s so that it is comparing timestamp not just date

$date_of_subscription = $row['exp_date'];

$date_converted = date_format($date_of_subscription,"m/d/Y");

if ($date_today > $date_converted) {

echo "expired";

}

Comment: oops i'm accidently compared with created date